# Get MySQL Data Using Powershell

Tags: mysql, powershell-2.0

I've been trying to set up powershell (v.2) to connect to my MySQL database, so that I can then

- get the number of rows returned, and
- export to csv

I've tried various scripts I've come across but have had the most success using the function on this page:

> http://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2011/04/powershell-run-mysql-querys-with-powershell/

Using this code I have been able to export a csv file using:

```
$result = run-MySQLQuery -ConnectionString "
    Server=127.0.0.1;
    Port=3312;
    Uid=xxxxx;
    Pwd=xxxxx;" `
    -Query "$SQL;"

$result | export-csv "c:\_emptyFolder\Test\test2.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

But, the csv file has the following data:

> ClassId2e4f51ef21dd47e99d3c952918aff9cd    pageHeaderEntry pageFooterEntry autosizeInfo    shapeInfo
>   033ecb2bc07a4d43b5ef94ed5a35d280               Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.TableHeaderInfo
>   9e210fe47d09416682b841769c78b8a3
>   27c87ef9bbda4f709f6b4002fa4af63c

when it should have:

> id action
>
> 1  a
>
> 2  a
>
> 1  b

Also whenI tried to get the number of rows returned using:

```
$result.length | write-host
```

I get `31` when it should be `27`

As you can tell I'm new to Powershell, any help on this matter would be appreciated.

I'm just using test data at the minute similar to:

```
CREATE TABLE test.`tb1` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL,`action` char(2) NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`action`,`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB;
INSERT INTO test.`tb1` VALUES (3,'a'),(3,'b'),(4,'a'),(4,'b');
```

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I would advise not using that function (or modifying it for use). He's returning the data via `Format-Table`, which makes it impossible to use as *data* - it's just formatted text output to the caller. You can avoid this by removing `|format-table` from the last line of the `try` block.

Comment: I think that may be the answer right there. Certainly it looks a lot more like what I was after now. The Row Count is now correct, and the CSV file has 'proper' data in it. I assume there is some 'trick' I need to learn to handle BLOB fields, but that's a minor point right now. Cheers (if you write it up I'll mark it as the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're using outputs data in a format that can't be used downstream. The results of the query are piped through `Format-Table`, which is nice for reading on screen but if you need to use those results as **data** then you're stuck.

Unless the task of a cmdlet/function is to format output, it should not be returning data through a `format-*` cmdlet. Let the caller handle the formatting, if necessary.

For this particular case, remove `|format-table` from the last line of the `try` block and the results will be returned as usable data.